# I tried predicting on 5rows of the dataset, but why does it keep predicting on the whole dataset?

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction, linearmodels

So I build a lm model in R on 65OOO rows (mydata) and I want to see only the predictions for the first 5 rows in order to see how good my model predicts. Below you can see the code I wrote to execute this but it keeps predicting the values of all 65000 rows. Is someone able to help me?

```
lm_model2002 <- lm(`AC: Volume` ~ `Market Area (L1)`,data=mydata)
summary(lm_model2002) 
df = head(data.frame(`Market Area (L1)`=mydata$`Market Area (L1)`),5)
predict(lm_model2002,newdata=df)
```

but now the real problem:  I took the first row of mydata and copied this row 5 times, then I made a vector that ranges from 1 to 2 and replaced one of the variables ( price per unit) with that vector. As a result, I want to predict the exact same rows but with only a different price, so that i am able to plot this evolution of a higher price:

```
lm_model3204<- lm(`AC: Volume` ~ log(price_per_unit)*(Cluster_country_hierarchical+`Loyalty-cumulative-volume-10`+`Loyalty-cumulative-orders-10`+`Loyalty-number-of-order-10`+price_discount+Incoterms)+Cluster_spg*(price_discount+Cluster_country_hierarchical)+price_discount*(Month+`GDP per capita`+`Loyalty-cumulative-orders-10`+`Loyalty-cumulative-volume-10`)+`Payer CustGrp`+`CRU Index`,data = mydata)
summary(lm_model3204)
test_data <- mydata[1:1,] 
df <- data.frame(test_data,ntimes=c(5)) 
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, rep, df$ntimes)) 
priceperunit<-seq(1,2,by=0.25) 
df$price_per_unit<-priceperunit 
pred <- predict(lm_model3204,newdata=df)
```

Comment: `df <- mydata %>% dplyr::slice(1:5)`

Comment: As I already write in other comments, use dput() to post data. From just an image, how can we use your data? Should we perhaps copy your data by hand to run some examples? Please help us to help you.

Comment: @Elia I can't because of privacy concerns, can't you figure it out like this?

Comment: Did you see my edited answer? did it solve your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Please use a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time you post a question.

You just have to predict the first five rows. Here an example with the in-built `iris` dataset

```
data("iris")

lm_model2002 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width,data=iris)
summary(lm_model2002)

predict(lm_model2002,newdata=iris[1:5,])
```

output:

```
> predict(lm_model2002,newdata=iris[1:5,])
       1        2        3        4        5 
5.744459 5.856139 5.811467 5.833803 5.722123
```

Or:

```
df <- head(iris,5)
predict(lm_model2002,newdata=df)
```

**EDIT**

After your last comment, to see the change in prediction by changing one of the independent variables

```
data(iris)

df <- iris[rep(1,5),]
Petal_Length<-seq(1,2,by=0.25)
df$Petal.Length<-Petal_Length

lm_model3204 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length+Sepal.Width,data=iris)
pred <- predict(lm_model3204,newdata=df)
```

Comment: Thanks,I want to share my real problem. I took the first row of mydata and copied this row 5 times, then I made a vector that ranges from 1 to 2 and replaced one of the variables ( price per unit) with that vector. As a result, I want to predict the exact same rows but with only a different price, so that i am able to plot this evolution of a higher price: test_data <- mydata[1:1,]
df <- data.frame(test_data,ntimes=c(5))
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, rep, df$ntimes))
priceperunit<-seq(1,2,by=0.25)
df$price_per_unit<-priceperunit and then ofcourse pred <- predict(lm_model3204,newdata=df)

Comment: post your data with `dput(your_df)`, or if it is too big `dput(head(your_df,20))`

Comment: It keeps predicting on the whole dataset but I only want predictions for the df set with 5 rows

Comment: Please post a reproducible example or your data by copying/pasting the output of `dput(your_data)`. In the meantime, I try to figure your problem out

Comment: this is our model: lm_model3204<- lm(`AC: Volume` ~ log(price_per_unit)*(Cluster_country_hierarchical+`Loyalty-cumulative-volume-10`+`Loyalty-cumulative-orders-10`+`Loyalty-number-of-order-10`+price_discount+Incoterms)+Cluster_spg*(price_discount+Cluster_country_hierarchical)+price_discount*(Month+`GDP per capita`+`Loyalty-cumulative-orders-10`+`Loyalty-cumulative-volume-10`)+`Payer CustGrp`+`CRU Index`,data = mydata)

Comment: I updated the question and gave a preview of the data which I call mydata